# Having problems to run a Fabric Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I have been fighting trying to get a fabric mod to work but to no avail. I have followed every tutorial known to man but I always get stuck in the same place.

```
package net.example;

import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;

import static net.minecraft.server.command.CommandManager.*;


public class ExampleMod implements ModInitializer {
  @Override
  public void onInitialize() {
    CommandRegistrationCallback.EVENT.register((dispatcher, registryAccess, environment) -> dispatcher.register(literal("foo")
        .executes(context -> {
      // For versions below 1.19, replace "Text.literal" with "new LiteralText".
      context.getSource().sendMessage(LiteralText("Called /foo with no arguments"));
 
      return 1;
    })));
  }
}
```

with that code this thing tells me that "CommandRegistrationCallback" "cannot be resolved" this is literally the code provided in https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:commands so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my other files:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'fabric-loom' version '1.1-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

version = project.mod_version
group = project.maven_group

repositories {
    // Add repositories to retrieve artifacts from in here.
    // You should only use this when depending on other mods because
    // Loom adds the essential maven repositories to download Minecraft and libraries from automatically.
    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
    // for more information about repositories.
}

dependencies {
    // To change the versions see the gradle.properties file
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    // Fabric API. This is technically optional, but you probably want it anyway.
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

    // Uncomment the following line to enable the deprecated Fabric API modules. 
    // These are included in the Fabric API production distribution and allow you to update your mod to the latest modules at a later more convenient time.

    // modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api-deprecated:${project.fabric_version}"
}

base {
    archivesName = project.archives_base_name
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version

    filesMatching("fabric.mod.json") {
        expand "version": project.version
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    // Minecraft 1.18 (1.18-pre2) upwards uses Java 17.
    it.options.release = 17
}

java {
    // Loom will automatically attach sourcesJar to a RemapSourcesJar task and to the "build" task
    // if it is present.
    // If you remove this line, sources will not be generated.
    withSourcesJar()

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

jar {
    from("LICENSE") {
        rename { "${it}_${base.archivesName.get()}"}
    }
}

// configure the maven publication
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }

    // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html for information on how to set up publishing.
    repositories {
        // Add repositories to publish to here.
        // Notice: This block does NOT have the same function as the block in the top level.
        // The repositories here will be used for publishing your artifact, not for
        // retrieving dependencies.
    }
}
```

fabric.mod.json:

```
{
  "schemaVersion": 1,
  "id": "example",
  "version": "${version}",

  "name": "example",
  "description": "idk",
  "authors": [
    "me"
  ],
  "contact": {
  },

  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "icon": "assets/example/icon.png",

  "environment": "*",
  "entrypoints": {
    "main": [
      "net.example.ExampleMod"
    ]
  },
  "mixins": [
  ],

  "depends": {
    "fabricloader": ">=0.14.17",
    "fabric-api": "*",
    "minecraft": "~1.19.4",
    "java": ">=17"
  },
  "suggests": {
    "another-mod": "*"
  }
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
# Done to increase the memory available to gradle.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx10G
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Fabric Properties
    # check these on https://fabricmc.net/develop
    minecraft_version=1.19.4
    yarn_mappings=1.19.4+build.2
    loader_version=0.14.19

# Mod Properties
    mod_version = 1.0.0
    maven_group = net.byescreen
    archives_base_name = byescreen

# Dependencies
    fabric_version=0.78.0+1.19.4
```

and here's my folder structure:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIRDv.png)

I am beyond myself, its 4am and I have achieved nothing. I need the internet's help for this one.

Already have all the latest versions of everything. Well java had version 20 and had to downgrade to the last 17 one. That's about it.

Already rebuilt with gradlew about 200 times, copied an pasted dozens of examples from the internet and nothing works. I always get to the problem that it doesn't find the "CommandRegistrationCallback" or any other class I need to just read the players commands.

Comment: Is [this](https://docproject.github.io/fabricmc_fabric/net/fabricmc/fabric/api/command/v1/CommandRegistrationCallback.html) the class you're trying to use? Because you're not importing it.

Comment: Your question is *close to* well-written, but a very important part that you are missing is the exact error message that you get. You have paraphrased it, but next time please make sure to copy-and-paste it and to format it as code. The **specifics** of an error message can often help figure out the concrete problem (though I think Federico got it right: you are probably just missing the `import`  statement for that class).

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary in>=1.19.4 to register with "CommandManager.literal("test")" instead of "literal("test")". when registering.

```
    CommandRegistrationCallback.EVENT.register((dispatcher, registryAccess, environment) -> {
        dispatcher.register(CommandManager.literal("test").executes(context -> {
            context.getSource().sendMessage(literal("working"));
            return 1;
         }));
    });
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP already imported the `CommandManager` class statically, so `literal` will be available in scope.

Comment: The main literal function must be from "net.minecraft.text.Text". Just at the register you need the method from CommandManager now.